# Xcode hide items in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

Why my Xcode hide items (UIImageView, Label etc.) in storyboard?
You can see on this picture, my labels are transparent in Document Outline.
And there are hidden on my Table View Controller.

[image: hidden labels]

Comment: See the views' frames and that the views are installed in the current size class. Just to point out, fix the autolayout issues please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of possible answers:

- Hidden views (Verify in the attribute inspector)
- Views uninstalled for this size class (you can check it at the bottom of the attribute inspector)
- Frame outside of the visible bounds of the superview. In order to verify this easily, go to Size inspector and set the X and Y value to 0.

You should check all these possibilities.

Comment: thanks, it just not clicked on install to this class :)

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all of your constraints on this view controller are they still not visible? More importantly, can you see anything at run time? Setting the values of these labels and images in cellForRowAtIndexPath is important. Also for some reason it seem you put an extra UIView named content view in the cell though that should not be the reason for your issues

Comment: thanks, but it just not clicked on install to this class :)